# What is the pricing structure for Firebase AppCheck?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, security, firebase-app-check

I want to ask: what are the pricing details for firebase AppCheck if I want to protect both my android and iOS apps using my hybrid development platform (flutter/react-native)?

Also what is the pricing or procedural details for increased API calls, to accommodate more API calls than the 10,000 per day allowed

Comment: There is no additional cost for app check. You can request to move to a higher tier if you need it, but you should not use app check for every single request. It is only intended for "high value" transactions, so 10,000 transactions is probably sufficient unless you have millions of DAU

Answer (score 5):

*firebaser here*

Firebase App Check is free of charge. You'd usually be able to see that on the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), but somehow it hasn't been added yet. The underlying provider *may* be a priced product (notably reCAPTCHA Enterprise), but App Check itself does not incur a cost.

If you are hitting the quota limits with a valid use-case, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of App Check is subject to the quotas and limits of the attestation providers you use.

- Play Integrity has a daily quota of 10,000 calls for its Standard API usage tier. https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview?authuser=0#usage-tiers
- SafetyNet has a daily quota of 10,000 calls. For information on requesting a quota increase, see the SafetyNet documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation?authuser=0#quota-monitoring
- reCAPTCHA v3 has a monthly quota of 1 million calls, as well as a 1,000 QPS limit: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq?authuser=0#are-there-any-qps-or-daily-limits-on-my-use-of-recaptcha
- reCAPTCHA Enterprise is no-cost for 1 million calls per month, and at cost beyond that: https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/pricing?authuser=0

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check